# Python REST API using dynamically-loaded persistent data

Tags: python, rest

I try to build a REST API in Python which relies on large data to be loaded dynamically in memory and processed. The data is loaded in Pandas DataFrames, but my question is not specific to Pandas and I might need other data structures.

After a request to the API, I would like to load the useful data (e.g., read from disk or from a DB) and keep it in memory because other requests relying on the same data should follow. After some time, I would need to drop the data in order to save memory.

In practice, I would like to keep a list of Pandas DataFrames in memory. The DataFrames in the list would be the DataFrames needed to fulfill the latest requests. Some DataFrames can be very large (e.g, several GBs), so I think that I cannot afford to retrieve them every time from a DB without a big overhead. This is why I want to keep them in memory for the next requests.

I started with Flask when the API relied on a single, fixed DataFrame. But now I cannot find a way to load dynamically new DataFrames and make them persistent across multiple requests. The loading of a new DataFrame should be triggered inside a request when necessary, and the new DataFrame should be available for the following requests. I do not know how to achieve that with Flask or with any other framework.